# How to build polymer app with some paper element example

Tags: javascript, polymer, paper-elements

I'am newbie in Polymer and Paper-Elements. I just make new blank polymer application, and try to run some example from paper-elements.

I created my blank polymer app using [this](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/start/install-2-0).
Then I added paper-elements using bower - `bower install --save PolymerElements/paper-elements`

Then I copy paste this [code](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-input):

```
<paper-input always-float-label label="Floating label"></paper-input>
<paper-input label="username">
  <iron-icon icon="mail" prefix></iron-icon>
  <div suffix>@email.com</div>
</paper-input>
```

So my whole element.html looks like this:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html"> 
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html" >
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html" >    
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html" >

<dom-module id="allegro-combo-box">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
      paper-input {
          max-width: 400px;
          margin: auto;
      }
      iron-icon, div[suffix] {
          color: hsl(0, 0%, 50%);
          margin-right: 12px;
      }
    </style>
    <h2>Hello [[prop1]]!</h2>
         
      <paper-input always-float-label label="Floating label"></paper-input>
      <paper-input label="username">
          <iron-icon icon="mail" prefix></iron-icon>
          <div suffix>@email.com</div>
      </paper-input>   

  </template>

  <script>
    /** @polymerElement */
    class Mextends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'my-element'; }
      static get properties() {
        return {
          prop1: {
            type: String,
            value: 'my-element'
          }
        };
      }
    }

    window.customElements.define(MyElement.is, MyElement );
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Unfortunately this code won't work. Only `<h2>Hello [[prop1]]!</h2>` is working, the elements from paper doesn't.

How to fix it?
I tried to add "async" in imports but this doesn't helped.

Please help.

This are some errors in console:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': this name has already been used with this registry
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeMethods' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your import statements for the paper elements don't have the correct path. Try changing the path as follows:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html" >
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html" >    
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html" >
```

Comment: Then maybe the path to your Polymer element is incorrect? Or do you have two bower_components directories?

Comment: If you only have one bower_components directory, then shouldn't the paths for the paper elements be the same as the polymer element? You tried adding the `../../` before the `bower_components` and the elements still don't load?

Comment: Hmm... Are you using Polymer 2.0? If so, you will need to install versions from the 2.0-preview branch of the paper elements. [Here is the preview branch for paper-input](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-input/tree/2.0-preview). Your paper-input bower version should be 2.0.0.

Comment: how ti install this via bower?

Comment: You'll need to specify the `2.0-preview` branch for each element, so for the paper-input element: `bower install PolymerElements/paper-input#2.0-preview`